# pass value from php project to java project

Tags: java, php, cookies, struts2

Here is my scenario.

1) I have a link `gotoJavaProject` as a `href link` in php project.

2) I want to pass a certain value (eg.`myValue`) when clicking the `gotoJavaProject` link which will lead to calling another java project.

3) I plan to send `the value as cookies` from php to a java web application.

php project is an existing project, and I just want to integrate with a new java project module.

As I am not familiar with php, I am quite stuck in figuring out how to achieve this.

Could anyone give me a guide or an example of how to pass a value in cookies from php to a java web application?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it as a parameter to your link.

```
http://example.com/?var=<?php echo $variable?>
```

I am not familiar with java, so I am not sure how you retreive get variables, but I assume it is pretty trivial

Comment: i believe this works good using urls, rather than cookies and cookies needs time & refresh too..